# Send a message after enter the data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem I need to enter the data and then display a message giving the amount I entered to the database correctly. The problem is that I can not know the amount that was introduced because it is a REST service and the variable does not work for me.

How to store in a variable all the results after entering them? It does not matter if they are failed or correct.

```
angular.forEach($scope.usersData, function(obj){
    dataUser = {
        users_id: obj.id,
        tipo_salida: 'NORMAL',
        dia_control: moment($scope.date_food).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
        amanecida: numValue(obj.amanecida),
        cena: numValue(obj.cena),
        te: numValue(obj.te),
        almuerzo: numValue(obj.almuerzo),
        desayuno: numValue(obj.desayuno),
        fecha_registro: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss')
    };
    diningroomsFactory.addDiningRooms(dataUser).then(function (response) {
        if(response.data.result === "success")
        {
            datCorrectCounter.push({
                data: response.data.result
            });
        }
    });
});

console.log(datCorrectCounter); //[] always empty
Notification.success("se introdujo correctamente: ", datCorrectCounter.length);
$state.go("diningroomsListNormals");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that `diningroomsFactory.addDiningRooms` returns a promise, inside a `forEach`, and `console.log(datCorrectCounter);` is being executed when there is no promise resolved yet.

A workaround here is `$q.all`, it combines multiple promises into a single promise that is resolved when all of the input promises are resolved.

```
var datCorrectCounter = [];
var promisesArray = []; // empty array to store all promises

angular.forEach($scope.usersData, function(obj){
    dataUser = {
        users_id: obj.id,
        tipo_salida: 'NORMAL',
        dia_control: moment($scope.date_food).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
        amanecida: numValue(obj.amanecida),
        cena: numValue(obj.cena),
        te: numValue(obj.te),
        almuerzo: numValue(obj.almuerzo),
        desayuno: numValue(obj.desayuno),
        fecha_registro: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss')
    };

    // store the promise in a variable
    var aPromise = diningroomsFactory.addDiningRooms(dataUser).then(function (response) {
        if(response.data.result === "success")
        {
            datCorrectCounter.push({
                data: response.data.result
            });
        }
    });

    // push the promise in the array
    promisesArray.push(aPromise);
});

$q.all(promisesArray).then(function(){
    console.log(datCorrectCounter); //it shouldn't be empty
    Notification.success("se introdujo correctamente: ", datCorrectCounter.length);
    $state.go("diningroomsListNormals");
});
```

I little detail about `$q.all`, if any of the promises is resolved with a rejection(fail), the resulting promise will be rejected with the same rejection value.

Hope it helps

Comment: lol, the one that gave the -1, can explain why? If you think something is wrong, name the reasons, so it can be done right.